# MySQL INSERT... SELECT Large Dataset of 420 Million Records

Tags: mysql, bigdata, large-data, load-data-infile

I have a large dataset of approximately 420 million records and I was able to load them into a temporary table in a timely manner of about 15 minutes using a `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement. I need this temporary table to stage the data because I do some cleaning on it before loading it into it's final destination.

The temporary table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `temporary_data` (
  `t_id` smallint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `record_type` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `record_value` varchar(512) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The target table that needs this data loaded is called `my_data` and it is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_data` (
  `s_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_id` smallint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `s_name` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_MY_DATA_S_NAME_T_ID` (`t_id`,`s_name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_MY_DATA_S_NAME` (`s_name`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MY_DATA_MY_PARENT` FOREIGN KEY (`t_id`) REFERENCES `my_parent` (`t_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The problem is, the query to load the data from the temporary table into `my_data` is very slow as I suspected it would be because `my_data` contains two indexes and a primary key. So far it has been running for over 6 hours with this query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_data (t_id, s_name)
SELECT t_id, s_name
FROM temporary_data;
```

I need to determine a way to speed up this query so it completes in a timely manner (under 30 minutes would be ideal).

**Some approaches I have considered:**

1. **Disable Indexes:** I might be able to get away with disabling/removing the `IDX_MY_DATA_S_NAME` index but I am relying on the unique index (`IDX_MY_DATA_S_NAME_T_ID`) to keep the data clean. This is a daily process that will run automatically and there will inevitably be some duplicates. Plus, it seems like it would be just as time-consuming to have to rebuild an index on a dataset this large when I go to enable the index again.
2. **Use DATA OUTFILE:** Export and re-import the cleaned data directly into `my_data`. I saw this recommended somewhere but after thinking about it, the indexes/PK would still be the contention point on re-insertion.
3. **Swap the tables:** Replacing `my_data` with `temporary_data` sounds attractive but this table has lots of foreign key relationships for the `s_id` field so I would want some assurance this approach would be worth the hassle of disabling foreign keys and re-enabling them. The child tables would contain significantly less records than `my_data` so re-enabling foreign keys might be negligible in that regard.
4. **LOAD DATA INFILE directly:** Load the data directly into `my_data` using conditionals in the SET part of the statement to make all fields `NULL` when it does not meet the cleanup criteria I was originally applying to `temporary_data` before loading it into `my_data`. It's hacky but it is relying on the assumption that LOAD DATA INFILE will be faster than INSERT... SELECT even in the face of indexing and there will be just one row of nulls to delete after it runs due to the unique constraint on the table.

None of these sound like terribly great ideas. If anyone has any tips I am all ears.

Comment: What does `show status like '%inno%wait%';` show?

Comment: Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free 0
Innodb_log_waits 0
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits 0
Innodb_row_lock_waits 0

Comment: I am using seperate file per table mode and I see the .ibd file continues to grow. The `show processlist` shows it executing as well in the `sending data` state.

Comment: Review the tips and techniques [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) .

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will definitely check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `s_id`; it is probably of no use.  Then promote `UNIQUE(t_id, s_name) as the` PRIMARY KEY`.  That cuts back on the number of tests performed for each row inserted.

Consider disabling `FOREIGN KEYs`; after all, they need to perform a check that might be redundant.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_data (t_id, s_name)
    SELECT t_id, s_name
    FROM temporary_data
    ORDER BY t_id, s_name;  -- Add this
```

That way, the inserts are not jumping around in the target table, thereby (hopefully) avoiding a lot of I/O.

Are you augmenting the table?  Or replacing it?  If replacing, there is a much better approach.

More...

Have you noticed that `INSERT IGNORE` wastes an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for every row that does not get inserted?  Let's try another approach...

```
INSERT INTO my_data (t_id, s_name)
    SELECT t.t_id, t.s_name
        FROM temporary_data AS t
        LEFT JOIN my_data AS m  USING(t_id, s_name)
        WHERE m.s_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY t.t_id, t.s_name;
```

The `ORDER BY` avoids jumping around during the `INSERT`.
The `LEFT JOIN` limits the activity to the "new" rows.
No `AUTO_INCREMENT` values will be burned.

How many rows will be inserted each time?  If it is millions, it would be better to break it into chunks.  See my [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) on chunking.  It *may* be faster than building a huge undo trail to toss eventually.

**Further discussion** -- Given

```
my_data:  PRIMARY KEY(s_id)  -- and s_id is AUTO_INCREMENT
my_data:  INDEX(t_id, s_name)
INSERT...SELECT...ORDER BY (t_id, s_name)  -- same as index
```

These are efficient:

- Since the `ORDER BY` and the secondary index are the same, the additions to the index will be done efficiently.
- Meanwhile, new `AUTO_INCREMENT` values will be generated sequentially on the "end" of the table.

The only thing better would be if `(t_id, s_name)` were Unique.  Then we could consider getting rid of `s_id` completely and changing the two indexes to this one:

```
PRIMARY KEY(t_id, s_name)
```

This would be a problem if other tables reference `s_id`.  A *possible* workaround is to keep s_id and have

```
PRIMARY KEY(t_id, s_name)
INDEX(s_id)   -- sufficient for AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I don't know enough about the big picture and the other queries to judge which direction to take.  So my original suggestion (before "Further discussion") was 'conservative'.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm augmenting. It's a daily ETL job I'm creating to load the 420 million records. The goal is to add new ones and never delete any. It finished after about 12 hours. I can't get rid of `s_id` because it is used as a foreign key for about seven other tables which will be much more sparse than what gets stored in `my_data`. I designed it this way so I wouldn't be storing a bunch of null fields for optional data that would come later thereby saving some space. I will give the new query a try with the `ORDER BY` clause and see if that helps. I'm also working on moving to SSD.

Comment: @Adam - I added More to my Answer.@Adam

Comment: Would you still recommend keeping the `ORDER BY t.t_id, t.s_name;` clause if the PK will remain `s_id`? Even though the compound unique index of t_id and s_name are not the PK, forcing them to be inserted in the same order each time will "make" it be inserted in PK order right?

Comment: @Adam - See my "further discussion".

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this. Interestingly, when I run the query now with the ORDER BY, I see it in the process list creating a sort index due to the ORDER BY clause and running df -h /mnt/* on my Digital Ocean box shows the size of the volume I have MySQL's tmpdir mapped to steadily increasing. Then after about 20-30 minutes the process list shows the command is now in "sleep" state and the tmpdir space is freed up. The results don't get inserted and there is no error. It just says that process is sleeping.

Comment: @Adam - `Sleep` means that the connection still exists (possible "pooled"), but the connection is not performing any SQL at the instant.  This is normal and harmless.  The gradual growing and abrupt shrinking of `tmpdir` space used implies that the query was complex enough to need an on-disk temp table.  In _some_ situations this can be avoided.  _Perhaps_ lowering the `512` would avoid the need for on-disk temp.